# Python SELECT Query PYODBC

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have the following function

```
def retrieve_metadata(self, sample_name, workflow_execution_id):
    print("Starting to retrieve meta data from Workflow for Sample {} and WorkflowExection {}".format(
        sample_name, workflow_execution_id))
    sql_query = """SELECT s.SampleName, s.ClientSampleId, s.ClientSubjectId, p.ProjectName, c.ClientName, s.ProjectId, e.WorkflowExecutionId from Sample s join project p on s.ProjectId = p.ProjectId join Client C on p.ClientId = c.ClientId left join SampleExecution e on e.SampleId = s.SampleId where s.SampleName = %s and e.WorkflowExecutionId = %s"""
    package_data = (sample_name, workflow_execution_id)
    for row in self.sql_reader.cursor.execute(sql_query, package_data):
        temp_meta = MetaData(row.SampleName,
                             row.ClientSampleId,
                             row.ClientSubjectId,
                             row.ProjectName,
                             row.ClientName,
                             row.ProjectId,
                             row.WorkflowExecutionId,
                             )
        self.input_data.append(temp_meta)
```

I recently changed the code to accept the parameters, but the error I am getting is

```
  File "/var/task/sql_scrapper.py", line 21, in retrieve_metadata
    for row in self.sql_reader.cursor.execute(sql_query, package_data):
ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

How can I resolve this with PYODBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    sql_query = """SELECT s.SampleName, s.ClientSampleId, s.ClientSubjectId, p.ProjectName, c.ClientName, s.ProjectId, e.WorkflowExecutionId from Sample s join project p on s.ProjectId = p.ProjectId join Client C on p.ClientId = c.ClientId left join SampleExecution e on e.SampleId = s.SampleId where s.SampleName = ? and e.WorkflowExecutionId = ?"""
```

changing from %s to ? resolved the issue.